# Looking for website to easily create charts for starting hand ranges (Texas Holdem)

Tags: texas-hold-em, starting-hand, range

Many poker websites
e.g. this one https://automaticpoker.com/strategy/free-poker-preflop-range-charts-with-printable-pdfs/
have lots of charts that rank the strength of starting hands in Texas Holdem.

Is there any online resource where I can easily create my own custom range charts? Sometimes I disagree with the resources I find, maybe because I'm playing at different sized tables, and maybe I want to create one chart per position (early, middle, late, under the gun, etc.). Also, as I play more I will learn more and I'll want to easily update some values.

I tried searching Google, but the only results were more opinions on starting hand ranges. Has anyone come across such a resource online anywhere?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @travis-cramer, are you affiliated in any way with the web address you have linked to? Welcome to poker.se.

Comment: @TobyBooth No, I am not. I just found it as a quick example off of Google.

Comment: I suggest rolling your own with Excell.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you two option :

- Online with [this](https://www.pokerhandrange.com/)
- On pc,(best in my opinion) Equilab is a free software
  [here](https://www.pokerstrategy.com/poker-software-tools/equilab-holdem/)
  where do you able to save your range.

Keep in mind : many poker room, like pokerstars, don't accept equilab running on pc while pokerstars running too.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeBetRange](https://freebetrange.com) fits your request perfectly. It's online range editor right in the browser.